# How to execute a function just before a react native app is hot reloaded

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a websocket based app in react native. Every time I hot reload, the socket connection is getting called, as a result, there is an overload of connections on the server. Moreover, sockets being sockets, they don't disconnect, but get connected with the refreshed app.

I have written a code to disconnect the socket in the componentWillUnmount() method of the app. However, it does not get executed when I press "r" on the console to reload the app.

Can someone please help?

Comment: what you realy wants ? execution of function before the app reload or what ?

Comment: Yes exactly that. Execution of a function just before app reload. There is a method like window.onBeforeUnload for ReactJS. I'm looking for something similar for react native.